# How can I call uiautomator api directly in Android project?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I would like to directly call Uiautomator API in a Android application to achieve automated testing.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get a `UiDevice` reference (which I guess what you want) you need

```
// Initialize UiDevice instance
mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
```

and to get the Instrumentation you have to be running you tests from `adb` so you won't be able to do it from an Activity.